# Access object from block which was defined inside different scope

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there any way to access object from block which was defined inside different scope? Sorry if it's confusing, I provide a little example:

```
def scope(&block)
  foo = "bar"
  instance_eval &block
end

scope do
  puts "foo is #{foo}"
end
```

I'd like to get the output:

```
"foo is bar"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You could explicitly pass parameters to the block.

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry that I didn't say it earlier. :( I'm looking for some way to do it without passing parameter to the block.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Look at my answer. Are you sure it's not what you want? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question is what you're trying to do, but the closest you can get is this:

```
def scope
  @foo = "bar"
  yield
end

scope do
  puts "foo is #{@foo}"
end
```

Note the use of an instance variable `@foo` instead of a local variable. You can't access the instance variable unless you do so explicitly, like this:

```
def scope
  foo = "bar"
  yield foo
end

scope do |foo|
  puts "foo is #{foo}"
end
```

But this is good. Otherwise it would be difficult to avoid conflicts with your local variables.

Note: I've also replaced your use of an explicit `&block` with the implicit `yield`. The `yield` form requires a block to be present, and has a simpler syntax, but it is largely a matter of style.